# linux binary must recognize and use local library for it

Tags: configuration, libraries

How do we have our own linux binary recognize and use its library/deps.  in local library i.e. in /usr/local/lib as we install it itself in /usr/local/bin ?

Answer (score 0):

Library search paths are controlled either at the system level by entries in the database `/etc/ld.so.cache` or at the application level by setting the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

**System-wide**

Add the directory (or directories) containing the required libraries into a text file under `/etc/ld.conf.d`. On some systems you may need to add them directly to `/etc/ld.conf`.

Run `ldconfig` to update the library database `/etc/ld.so.cache`

**Application**

Set or extend `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include the directory (or directories)  containing the required libraries for the context of just your application:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH}" /usr/local/bin/your_app arg1 arg2…
```

If you can guarantee that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is empty, or contains nothing of relevance to your application you can simplify this invocation:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib /usr/local/bin/your_app arg1 arg2…
```

In either case, if you already have `/usr/local/bin` in your `$PATH` you can simplify by not using an explicit path to the application. For example,

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib your_app arg1 arg2…
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @roaima's answer, you can compile your application to explicitly look in the local library. Add

```
-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib
```

to your compile command (assuming you're using `gcc`).